# Independency Of Random variable $X$ and $Y$ , Given Joint density Function.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> **Question:** Let $c\in \Bbb R$ be constant. let $X$ and $Y$ be random variable with joint probability density function
> $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} cxy&~0<x<y<1\\~\\0& \text{ otherwise}
> \end{cases}$$
>
> (1)  $c=\frac 1 8$
>
> (2) $c=8$
>
> (3) $X$ and $Y$ are independent.
>
> (4) $P(X=Y)=0$

using
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\int_{y=x}^{y=1} cxy~  \text{dy dx}=1$$
we have $c=8$.
For  option $(4)$  My approach is since Joint distribution has density and Lebesgue measure of line is $0$. so option (4) is correct.

" Since joint distribution is absolutely continuous ,so $X$ and $Y$ are absolutely continuous and hence continuous. Hence $X-Y$ is continuous .so option (4) is correct."

**Question:** Is above approach for opt (4) is correct?

For option (3)  we can check it by finding CDF of $X$ and $Y$ and joint CDF. and check whether they are products out or not . but This question was asked in exam .so I think  there is another easy way to do it .

**Question:** Is there another approach  for option $3$?

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ continuous does not imply that $X-Y$ is continuous.

Comment: @geetha290krm  Yes I missed $X-X=0$ would be counter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (3), they aren't independent because $P(X > \frac 12, Y < \frac 12) = 0$ but $P(X > \frac 12) P(Y < \frac 12) \ne 0$.

For (4), the first thing you write is the correct approach: since Joint distribution has density and Lebesgue measure of line is $0$, $P(X=Y) = 0$.  As pointed out in the comments, it is not true that $X$ and $Y$ are continuous implies $X-Y$ is continuous.

Comment: What is your approach for $P(X > \frac 12) P(Y < \frac 12) \ne 0$? My approach is since $(\frac 1 2 ,\infty)\times \Bbb R$ contain some 'positive area' ,so $P(X> \frac 1 2)>0$ . If you are using different approach then  please share it.

Comment: @MeetPatel Yeah, that's basically it.  That tells you both random variables are fully supported on $[0,1]$, so there is positive probability they're in any interval with positive width.  You could also do it with integrals, the same way you determined $c$ (just with slightly different bounds of integration).